# Dataframe tuple not being created as expected

Tags: python, pandas

Using the below code to create a dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd


col1 = [[1,2,3]]
col2 = [['a1','a2','a3']]
col3 = [['b1','b2','b3']]
col4 = ['id1']

df_test = pd.DataFrame(
            {
             'col1': col1,
             'col2': col2,
             'col3': col3,
            'col4': col4
            })
df_test = df_test.set_index('col4')
```

creates :

```
    col1    col2    col3
col4            
id1 [1, 2, 3]   [a1, a2, a3]    [b1, b2, b3]
```

I'm attempting to create a dataframe of format

```
col4
id1    ([1, a1, b1], [2, a2, b2], [3, a3, b3])
dtype: object
```

Each corresponding index of the list of lists c1,c2,c3 contains an element in the tuple.

Using :

```
df_test = df_test.apply(tuple, axis=1)
df_test
```

to convert the dataframe renders :

```
df_test = df_test.apply(tuple, axis=1)
df_test
```

How to create a dataframe of format ? :

```
col4
id1    ([1, a1, b1], [2, a2, b2], [3, a3, b3])
dtype: object
```

using either

1.the original source data :

```
col1 = [[1,2,3]]
col2 = [['a1','a2','a3']]
col3 = [['b1','b2','b3']]
col4 = ['id1']
```

or

2. creating the tuple format after creating the dataframe :

   df_test = pd.DataFrame(
   {
   'col1': col1,
   'col2': col2,
   'col3': col3,
   'col4': col4
   })
   df_test = df_test.set_index('col4')

Using :

```
pd.DataFrame([tuple(zip(*np.array([df_test['col1'],df_test['col2'], df_test['col3']]).T.tolist()))], index= df_test.index)
```

renders :

```
0   1   2
col4            
id1 ([1, 2, 3],)    ([a1, a2, a3],) ([b1, b2, b3],)
```

I've tried wrapping the elements in a list :

```
pd.DataFrame([tuple(zip(*np.array([list(df_test['col1']),list(df_test['col2']), list(df_test['col3'])]).T.tolist()))], index= df_test.index)
```

but same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

After dataframe creation, use:

```
>>> df_test.apply(lambda x: tuple(list(i) for i in zip(*x)), axis=1)
id1    ([1, a1, b1], [2, a2, b2], [3, a3, b3])
dtype: object
```

You can try:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([tuple(zip(*np.array([col1, col2, col3]).T.tolist()))], index=col4)

                                           0
id1  ([1, a1, b1], [2, a2, b2], [3, a3, b3])
```

Comment: please see question update, shouldn't your code also work when using a dataframe instead of the columns ?

Comment: Did you try: `df_test.apply(lambda x: tuple(list(i) for i in zip(*x)), axis=1)`?

Comment: A shortest solution: `df_test.apply(lambda x: tuple(np.array([*x]).T), axis=1)` :-)